# How to get output from Rails Runner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Rails Runner script and I want to see what values are set in a variable in the script?

Usual `puts` doesn't work...

Answer (score 5):

Ahh. Figured it out, use `STDOUT.flush` after each `puts` in the script.

http://redgreenrepeat.com/2016/08/20/til-feedback-in-rails-runner/